# Does custom setting fields value changes shows in setup audit trail?

Tags: customsetting, setup-audit-log

Does custom setting fields value changes shows in setup audit trail ?

I don't find changes in audit trail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is no. As per salesforce standard functionality this feature is not available right now.

Refer the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gddx1UAB/include-custom-settings-insertschangesdeletes-in-setup-audit-trail)